# NullReferenceException occurs when adding new labels in panel

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I added a panel to `Form1` component. That panel is named `panel1`.

When browsing a generic list, I want to add labels dynamically. Look to my little code:

```
if (list.Count > 0)
{

    foreach (TLClass item in list)
    {
        Label key = new Label();
        key.Text = item.Key;
        panel1.Container.Add(key);  //here throws an exception

        Label code = new Label();
        code.Text = item.Code.ToString();
        panel1.Container.Add(code);

        Label en = new Label();
        en.Text = item.Languages["EN-EN"].ToString();
        panel1.Container.Add(en);


        Label fr = new Label();
        fr.Text = item.Languages["FR-FR"].ToString();
        panel1.Container.Add(fr);

        Label nl = new Label();
        nl.Text = item.Languages["NL-NL"].ToString();
        panel1.Container.Add(nl);

        Label ro = new Label();
        ro.Text = item.Languages["RO-RO"].ToString();
        panel1.Container.Add(ro);

        Form1.ActiveForm.Container.Add(panel1);
    }
}
```

After line `panel1.Container.Add(key);`, immediately throws an exception `NullReferenceException`.

Why ? Where's my mistake ?

[image]

**Problem solved**
I called with `Controls` instead of `Container`

Comment: Did you check whether panel1 is null? 99% likely it is, and the real question is "why?"

Comment: How about `panel1.Container`?

Comment: @Eric: I wrote `panel1 = new Panel()` but same issue

Comment: What event are you doing this in? Has the panel been sited (is panel1.Container null)? Please learn to use the debugger: you could very quickly determine what is null.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: an example ? I already used this.

Comment: @Michael: Look in the debugger to see exactly what is null.

Comment: Also, unrelated, you don't have to check whether list.Count > 0.  If it is zero, the foreach will return no enumerated objects.

Comment: It should not simply be  panel1.Controls.Add?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add controls to the container.
Which should be the parent form, but when you Add the parent form is not set.
However the right way is to add to the controls collection of the panel

```
panel1.Controls.Add(key);
```